# Problems with orx doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, typo3-flow

I have something like:

```
$languages = ["English", "German", "Spanish"];
```

The Job Entity:

```
/**
 * @Flow\Entity
 */
class Job {
    /**
     * The name of first language for the job (M:1 unidirectional)
     *
     * @var \PATH\Language
     * @ORM\ManyToOne
     */
    protected $language1;

    /**
     * The name of second language for the job (M:1 unidirectional)
     *
     * @var \PATH\Language
     * @ORM\ManyToOne
     */
    protected $language2;
}
```

And Language Entity:

```
/**
 * @Flow\Entity
 */
class Language
{

    /**
     * The language name
     *
     * @var string
     * @Flow\Identity
     * @Flow\Validate(type="Text")
     * @Flow\Validate(type="NotEmpty")
     * @Flow\Validate(type="StringLength", options={ "minimum"=1, "maximum"=80})
     * @ORM\Column(length=80)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

How can I get all jobs with language1 OR language2 in $languages?
I tried the following, but it does not work...

I get empty results back.

```
$queryBuilder
            ->resetDQLParts()
            ->select("job")
            ->from("Job", "job")
            ->andWhere(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
                        $queryBuilder
                            ->innerJoin('job.language1', 'language1')
                            ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->in("language1.name", $languages)),
                        $queryBuilder
                            ->innerJoin('job.language2', 'language2')
                            ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->in("language2.name", $languages))
                )
            );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Try printing the SQL to see what isn't quite right by using `->getSQL()` at the end and echoing it.

Comment: Can´t do a var_dump because it is being called via ajax

Comment: Sure you can, die(var_dump($var)); and check your f12 dev tools response from the ajax request.

Comment: I do get >>> Expression of type 'Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder' not allowed in this context.

Exception Code 0
Exception Type InvalidArgumentException
Thrown in File Packages/Libraries/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Base.php
Line 95

Comment: I am still not sure what the problem is. No it is probably not necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149614/discussion-between-tiero-l-and-doug).

Comment: they are on the same table. But i need to access: language1.name and language2.name

Comment: In Flow it should be like this, without the targetEntity parameter, just the @var

Comment: I do not think it is about the entity structure, it does work because it is used in other places. It is more about the doctrine query

Comment: Well I've covered the queries but you've not said what is not working. No mention of errors or whether you get a blank result.

Comment: I get an empty results back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the query you have written, it's certainly not how I've used the QueryBuilder in the past. I've rewritten it how I'd use it.

The language fields do not state which entity they reference it should be:

```
/** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity='AppBundle\Entity\Language')
```

Assuming a table structure of:

```
ID | Job Name | Language1 | Language2
1  | Job1     | French    | English
2  | Job2     | English   | Spanish
```

The SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` 
     WHERE `language1` IN ("English", "French") 
     OR    `language2` IN ("English", "French");
```

Which translates to:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('job')            
        ->where('job.language1 IN (:languages)')
        ->orWhere('job.language2 IN (:languages)')
        ->setParameter("languages", $languages)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

However with a table structure of:

```
-- Jobs
ID | Job Name | Language1 | Language2
1  | Job1     | 1         | 2
2  | Job2     | 2         | 3

-- Languages
ID | Language
1  | French
2  | English
3  | Spanish
```

You'd need something like this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('job')
        ->leftJoin('job.language1', 'language1')
        ->leftJoin('job.language2', 'language2')
        ->where('language1.language IN (:languages)')
        ->orWhere('language2.language IN (:languages)')
        ->setParameter("languages", $languages)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Doug, but I did not get it to work yet.

Comment: @Tiero What didn't work? You should provide the relevant parts of your entities including the join yaml or annotations so we can see what you are actually attempting to-do.

Comment: The job entity is in the question.

Comment: Okay the language entity is in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem too, that's why Dougs solution was not working for me. After fixing that problem and the help of his solution I came up with this:

```
    $queryBuilder
        ->leftJoin('Path\Language', 'language1', JOIN::LEFT_JOIN,  "job.language1 = language1")
        ->leftJoin('Path\Language', 'language2', JOIN::LEFT_JOIN,  "job.language2 = language2")
        ->andWhere(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->in("language1.name", ":languages"),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->in("language2.name", ":languages")
            )
        )->setParameter("languages", $languages);
```